# Install OS 10.13 without iTunes 12.7

Tags: macos, itunes

I need ability to manage my apps but not the app Store. Can OS 10.13 be installed without installing iTunes 12.7. Where can I download OS 10.13 that does not include iTunes?. I will be installing on a Mac Book Pro - Mid 2014.

Answer (score 2):

You can install [install iTunes 12.6.3](https://www.macrumors.com/2017/10/09/apple-itunes-with-app-store-included/) on top of / over iTunes 12.7 for all OS that support iTunes 12.7 and both are compatible with iOS 11.

[Apple KB: Deploy apps in a business environment with iTunes](https://support.apple.com/HT208079)

You need the direct link, it apparently does not appear as an update.
[Mac link.](https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/itunes12/091-33628-20170922-EF8F0FE4-9FEF-11E7-B113-91CF9A97A551/iTunes12.6.3.dmg)
[Windows 32 bit link.](https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/itunes12/091-33627-20170922-EF8CB708-9FEF-11E7-8504-92CF9A97A551/iTunesSetup.exe)
[Windows 64-bit Link.](https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/itunes12/091-33626-20170922-F51D3530-A003-11E7-8324-03D19A97A551/iTunes64Setup.exe)

If you've already been using 12.7 you may have luck importing your 12.7 lib  to a clean 12.6.3 Library, as outlined on MacRumors, but I had no joy.

I ended up restoring a backup of my Library [just the catalog not all the tunes] from a time before i updated to 12.7.